# Why does the while loop not break on success?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I'm taking my first steps to code and I'm working on small program that generates a random number and the user has to guess numbers till the chosen number matches the generated number.

For some reason, even when I'm giving the correct number the while loop is not breaking.

```
import random
secretnumber = random.randint(1,10)
chosennumber = 0

while secretnumber != chosennumber:
    print("Number selected. Please select a number between 1 and 10")
    print ("hint! The number is " + str(secretnumber))
    chosennumber = input()
    if secretnumber!= chosennumber:
        continue
    print("please try again, think about the hint")
    chosennumber = input()
    if chosennumber == secretnumber:
        break
print("you've guessed the correct number " + str(secretnumber))
```

Comment: Just like you did that conversion to string at the end (`str(secretnumber)`), you should do that other way around to your chosennumber by converting it to integer with: `if int(chosennumber) == secretnumber:`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return value of `input()` is a string. Comparing a string to an integer will always yield `False`. You need to cast either the string to int or the int to string for comparison, to make sure you're comparing variables of the same type.

```
import random
secretnumber = random.randint(1,10)
chosennumber = 0

while secretnumber != chosennumber:
    print("Number selected. Please select a number between 1 and 10")
    print ("hint! The number is " + str(secretnumber))
    chosennumber = int(input().strip())
    if secretnumber!= chosennumber:
        continue
    print("please try again, think about the hint")
    chosennumber = int(input().strip())
    if chosennumber == secretnumber:
        break
print("you've guessed the correct number " + str(secretnumber))
```

Comment: Thanks. Converting the chosennumber to an integer did indeed help. Note that I tried `while str(secretnumber) != str(chosennumber) :` did not work.